# Longitudinal analysis using sampling weigths in R

Tags: r, survey, mixed-models, weighted, longitudinal

I have longitudinal data from two surveys and I want to do a pre-post analysis. Normally, I would use `survey::svyglm()` or `svyVGAM::svy_vglm` (for multinomial family) to include sampling weights, but these functions don't account for the random effects. On the other hand, `lme4::lmer` accounts for the repeated measures, but not the sampling weights.

For continuous outcomes, I understand that I can do

```
w_data_wide <- svydesign(ids = ~1, data = data_wide, weights = data_wide$weight)

svyglm((post-pre) ~ group, w_data_wide)
```

and get the same estimates that I would get if I could use `lmer(outcome ~ group*time + (1|id), data_long)` with weights [please correct me if I'm wrong].

However, for categorical variables, I don't know how to do the analyses. `WeMix::mix()` has a parameter *weights*, but I'm not sure if it treats them as sampling weights. Still, this function can't support multinomial family.

So, to resume: can you enlighten me on how to do a pre-post test analysis of categorical outcomes with 2 or more levels? Any tips about packages/functions in R and how to use/write them would be appreciated.

I give below some data sets with binomial and multinomial outcomes:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)

data_long <- data.table(
  id=rep(1:5,2),
  time=c(rep("Pre",5),rep("Post",5)),
  outcome1=sample(c("Yes","No"),10,replace=T),
  outcome2=sample(c("Low","Medium","High"),10,replace=T),
  outcome3=rnorm(10),
  group=rep(sample(c("Man","Woman"),5,replace=T),2),
  weight=rep(c(1,0.5,1.5,0.75,1.25),2)
)

data_wide <- dcast(data_long, id~time, value.var = c('outcome1','outcome2','outcome3','group','weight'))[, `:=` (weight_Post = NULL, group_Post = NULL)]
```

EDIT

As I said below in the comments, I've been using `lmer` and `glmer` with variables used to calculate the weights as predictors. It happens that `glmer` returns a lot of problems (convergence, high eigenvalues...), so I give another look at @ThomasLumley answer in this post and others (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-June/315529.html | https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89204/fitting-multilevel-models-to-complex-survey-data-in-r).

So, my question is now if a can use participants id as clusters in `svydesign`

```
library(survey)
w_data_long_cluster <- svydesign(ids = ~id, data = data_long, weights = data_long$weight)
summary(svyglm(factor(outcome1) ~ group*time, w_data_long_cluster, family="quasibinomial"))

                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)         1.875e+01  1.000e+00  18.746   0.0339 *
groupWoman         -1.903e+01  1.536e+00 -12.394   0.0513 .
timePre             5.443e-09  5.443e-09   1.000   0.5000  
groupWoman:timePre  2.877e-01  1.143e+00   0.252   0.8431
```

and still interpret `groupWoman:timePre` as differences in the average rate of change/improvement in the outcome over time between sex groups, as if I was using mixed models with participants as random effects.

Thank you once again!

Comment: You can perhaps get better answers here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: maybe https://notstatschat.rbind.io/2018/04/01/svylme/  ?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that package, @AnthonyDamico. I would have tried it,but, unfortunately, it is not available for the R version that I'm using (3.6.3)

Answer (score 1):

A linear model with `svyglm` does not give the same parameter estimates as `lme4::lmer`. It *does* estimate the same parameters as `lme4::lmer` if the model is correctly specified, though.

Generalised linear models with `svyglm` or `svy_vglm` don't estimate the same parameters as `lme4::glmer`, as you note.  However, they do estimate perfectly good regression parameters and if you aren't specifically interested in the variance components or in estimating the realised random effects (BLUPs) I would recommend just using `svy_glm`.

Another option if you have non-survey software for random effects versions of the models is to use that.  If you scale the weights to sum to the sample size and if all the clustering in the design is modelled by random effects in the model, you will get at least a reasonable approximation to valid inference. That's what I've seen recommended for Bayesian survey modelling, for example.

Comment: thank you for your answer. As it's my first time using mixed models, I'm not sure what you mean by "if you aren't specifically interested in the variance components or in estimating the realised random effects (BLUPs)". So far, what I've done is use `lme4::lmer` and `lme4::glmer` to estimate differences between groups over time, taking as time-invariant covariates the variables from which I calculated the weights (these weights do not total the sample size because they were truncated). Do you consider this procedure appropriate?

Comment: Yes, that's appropriate.